# WorkManager: Do you need to manually dispose of Observables in a Worker?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Lets say in your `doWork()` method you have an Observable that emits the progress of a download, do you need to manually dispose of this Observable to avoid memory leaks? And thus use RxWorker?

According to this [Do I have to unsubscribe from completed observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826478/do-i-have-to-unsubscribe-from-completed-observable)
"On the JVM, an anonymous inner class maintains a reference to the outer class." But in this case our outer class is not an activity or fragment, it's a Worker. So would it leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RxWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker) and that will take care of disposing for you.