# how come we need to unsubscribe from an Observerable ?

Tags: rxjs5, angularfire2

Do we ever need to unsubscribe from an Observable? When is the time we need to use unsubscribe?

I read an angularfire2 article talking about using firebase.auth to check user's login status. In the end of code, he unsubscribes from auth.subscribe.
https://javebratt.com/angularfire2-email-auth/ (please see app.component.ts).

I was really confused, since I thought the Observable will "unsubscribe" itself after completed or on error.

[Do we need to unsubscribe from observable that completes/errors-out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334931/do-we-need-to-unsubscribe-from-observable-that-completes-errors-out)
and
[Do you need to unsubscribe from Angular 2 http calls to prevent memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct about unsubscribing on `complete` or `error` notification.

I think the key is the comment in [`getAuth()` method in `auth.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/d422e62b46a80d9fb12c9a9e2cf1cf2f7db04dd3/src/auth/auth.ts#L129):

> Please observe the actual authState asynchronously by subscribing to the auth service: af.auth.subscribe()

So you should subscribe with `af.auth.subscribe(...)` to be notified when the actual `authState` changes. This means that it doesn't complete (similarly to `Observable.fromEvent(...)`) and you have to unsubscribe manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not only do `complete` and `error` events unsubscribe from the Observable, but that's actually the [proper way](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.c2k8x7h5y) to unsubscribe.

The advantages of completing vs unsubscribing, as listed in this post, are:

- usually less code
- better factored / designed code; your completion rules are in one place; where a subscription begins and where it ends are in one place
- you take advantage of the `complete` event to write any "completion / clean up" code (there's no `unsubscribe` event)

Answer (score 0):

I also got an answer from the author:

**Jorge Vergara**

You don't need to (do *unsubscribe()*). I do it because I only want the observable to send people to those pages on app startup, if I'm going to log my user in or make some changes in auth I don't want that observer firing up and redirecting my users somewhere.