# Angular 2+ using RxJS - complete vs unsubscribe regarding take(1) and first()

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Reading through some documentation and questions, I've found it to be a little unclear as to weather using first() or take(1) actually unsubscribe when they complete. I suppose my confusion is around 'complete' vs 'unsubscribe'. To say an observable completes, does that also mean the subscriptions are unsubscribed? I'm thinking about this for garbage collection, whereas I need to know that the observable isn't retaining any references after first() or take(1) complete.

If these functions do not unsubscribe, I need to know the easiest way to unsubscribe after completion. Or is this even necessary?

Comment: When an observable completes (or errors), all subscribers are automatically unsubscribed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41336428/6680611

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things from the source code,

> (do) first() and take(1) actually unsubscribe when they complete

It would appear so.

**take.ts**

```ts
protected _next(value: T): void {
  const total = this.total;
  const count = ++this.count;
  if (count <= total) {
    this.destination.next(value);
    if (count === total) {
      this.destination.complete();
      this.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

> To say an observable completes, does that also mean the subscriptions are unsubscribed?

In **Subscription.ts**, came across this (not seen it in documentation)

```ts
/**
 * Adds a tear down to be called during the unsubscribe() of this
 * Subscription.
 *
   ...
 */
add(teardown: TeardownLogic): Subscription {
```

so I figured teardown could be used to verify that unsubscribe is called.

```ts
const source1 = Observable.range(1, 10).take(6)

const subscription1 = source1.subscribe(x => console.log('subscription1'))
  .add(() => console.log('teardown1'))
// Emits 6x then 'teardown1'

const subscription2 = source1.take(4).subscribe(x => console.log('subscription2'))
  .add(() => console.log('teardown2'))
// Emits 4x then 'teardown2'
```

but note that `take()` only unsubscribes downstream of itself, not **all** subscribers to the observable

```ts
const source2 = Observable.range(1, 10)

const subscription3 = source2.subscribe(x => console.log('subscription3'))
  .add(() => console.log('teardown3'))
// Emits 10x then 'teardown3'

const subscription4 = source2.take(5).subscribe(x => console.log('subscription4'))
  .add(() => console.log('teardown4'))
// Emits 5x then 'teardown4'
```

> I need to know that the observable isn't retaining any references after first() or take(1) complete.

This is a bit trickier, here is the `Observable.subscribe()` method. Seems the observer isn't keeping a reference to any of it's three parameters, but rather the subscription is keeping a reference to the observable.

```ts
subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void),
          error?: (error: any) => void,
          complete?: () => void): Subscription {

  const { operator } = this;
  const sink = toSubscriber(observerOrNext, error, complete);

  if (operator) {
    operator.call(sink, this.source);
  } else {
    sink.add(this.source ? this._subscribe(sink) : this._trySubscribe(sink));
  }

  if (sink.syncErrorThrowable) {
    sink.syncErrorThrowable = false;
    if (sink.syncErrorThrown) {
      throw sink.syncErrorValue;
    }
  }
  return sink;
}
```

This can be seen in the following test code. While the subscription is active (closed: false), the subscriber has the observable referenced in `_subscriptions`

```ts
const source3 = Observable.interval(1000)
const subscription5 = source3.subscribe(x => {})
console.log(source3)
console.log(subscription5)
```

Console output:

```ts
IntervalObservable 
  period: 1000
  scheduler: AsyncScheduler {...}
  _isScalar: false
  __proto__: Observable

Subscriber 
  closed: false
  destination: SafeSubscriber {...}
  isStopped: false
  syncErrorThrowable: false
  syncErrorThrown: false
  syncErrorValue: null
  _parent: null
  _parents: null
  _subscriptions: [AsyncAction]
  __proto__: Subscription
```

but when we close the subscription with a `take(1)`,

```ts
const source3 = Observable.interval(1000).take(1)
const subscription5 = source3.subscribe(x => {})
console.log(source3)
console.log(subscription5)
```

Subscriber `_subscriptions` is set to null, releasing the reference.

```ts
Subscriber 
  closed: true
  destination: SafeSubscriber {...}
  isStopped: true
  syncErrorThrowable: false
  syncErrorThrown: false
  syncErrorValue: null
  _parent: null
  _parents: null
  _subscriptions: null
  __proto__: Subscription
```

I'm not sure this can be considered a definitive proof for all observable/operator/subscriber chains, but is at least indicative of a way to verify your particular use-case.